# How to Return the nth matching pattern in Business Objects Web Intelligence 4.2

Tags: crystal-reports, business-intelligence, business-objects

I have created the following variables in Business Objects 4.2:

```
2cPat =Pos([Service Item Value];"2C" )

2C Ref #1 =If([2cPat])=0 Then "" Else (Substr([Service Item Value];[2cPat] ;10 ))
```

what the `2cPat` variable do is looks on the `[Service Item Value]` column row by row and finds the 1st word that starts with `2C`

What the `2C Ref #1` variable does is extracts the matched pattern that starts with `2C` and is 10 characters in total length.

The problem is that I can have more than 1 `2C` match per row and I need to extract all the ones that appear on each row.

My approach will be to create another variable called `2C Ref #2`but the problem that I have is how do I make the code ignore the already found `2C` that has been stored on `2C Ref #1`.

Here is a sample of how the data looks right now:

```
Service Item Value                                                                                                        2C Ref #1    2C Ref #2    2C Ref #3    2C Ref #4    2C Ref #5
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----------   ----------   ----------   ----------   ----------
E2E: 2C03144250 ;    Site 1: 2C03144220; Site 2: 2C03144245  Site 2: EAFE03144169  C72/273918                             2C03144250   2C03144220
Site 1: 2C03100386; Site 2: 2C03100440 ; End to End: 2C03100444  SITE1: EAGE02897836 ; SITE2: EAFE03100362  C72/266267    2C03100386   2C03100440           
ETHWIR000214950, e2e 2C02474833 , 2C02474832 POP - 2C02474831 CX                                                          2C02474833   2C02474832
```

Because of the length of the data sample I cannot make it fit properly here on Stack Overflow but please also see a screenshot that I have taken:
[image]

Comment: can you post a sample string on how your data look like... will provide a solution

Comment: @Siva i have added the code as requested. any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried and have succeeded but to extract the whole string you need write many formula as I couldn't find any loops functionality in WEBI.

Here goes the solution:

First extract the first `2c` string and then store the remaining string in new variable and in step 2 extract the successive `2c` string and then store the remaining in another variable this way you need to go till the end of string later if you need you can concatenate the all individual `2c` strings.

Formula for first `2c` string

```
=Substr([Column1];Pos([Column1];"2C");10)
```

Now extract the remaining string other than this string:

Remaining string excluding the forst 2c part `"remainining` formula:

```
=Right([Column1];Length([Column1])-(Pos([Column1];"2C")+10))
```

Now extract the next 2c value from remaining string

```
=Substr([remaining];Pos([remaining];"2C");10)
```

Now you need to extract the next part of the string excluding above 2c values.

Attaching the screenshot of what I have done.

Try and let me know

[image]